# Url.Action not routing correctly in .NET Hybrid MVC/Web Forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a file structure like so:

```
/Areas/ProjectApp/Controllers/
/Areas/ProjectApp/Models/
/Areas/ProjectApp/Views/
```

Inside Views folder I have a projectlist.cshtml which has a link like so:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index")">Project Home</a>
```

The project home is actual at:

```
http://localhost:57538/ProjectApp
```

The route though gets generated as such:

```
http://localhost:57538/?action=Index&controller=Home
```

That in turn leads it to:

```
http://localhost:57538/ (the home page of the bigger app)
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually using completely different areas for your controllers, models, and views, or is that just the way you have setup your URLs? Routes don't go to views, they go to controllers. Please show an example of a controller, model, and view (a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Also, if using areas, show your `AreaRegistration` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using areas, in which case you have to specify the area in the `Url.Action`.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { Area = "ProjectApp" })">Project Home</a>
```